# simple manipulation of a data frame column

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a data frame called `data` which I read in from a CSV file in my R script. There is a column (named `Bool` which is in that data frame which has all values as FALSE.

Given an integer `x`, I want to make the first `x` rows in the column `Bool` TRUE.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could

```
data[1:x, 'Bool'] = TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe I've just been using R too long, but the Q seems really basic, one that *ought* to be clear if one had read the documentation. However, adapting an earlier comment on a similar question: "surprisingly, http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf doesn't have this information in it. Most of the other R introductions should, though ... e.g. pp. 36ff. of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Robinson-icebreaker.pdf (see http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html generally) ". Anyone have other suggestions for great contributed docs for tasks like simple indexing and replacement?

Comment: @Ben Bolker It is wonderful that people answer questions that are _rephrasings of information_ found in the R documentation. I've learnt far more R from the google+stackoverflow combination than from the manuals or the R help system.

Comment: Alternatively `data$Bool[1:x] <- TRUE`